# Showing "open with" dialog on Android

Tags: android, mobile

How can I give chance to user to choose application for opening a link?

For example, user has 3 browsers and he set Firefox as default browser. I want to give chance to open a link with Opera to user when user long click link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [Intent.createChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#createChooser%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" );
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri), "Choose browser"));
```

Answer (score 4):

PackageManager.queryIntentActivities() returns all of the activities that can handle a particular Intent.

With the Intent you passed in to it, to now use it to launch one of the activities in the returned list, you use Intent.setComponent with a ComponentName built from the packageName and name of the activity you want in that list.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Uri with your URL and pass it to an Intent like so:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse( "http://www.google.com" );
startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri ) );
```

Is this what you're looking to accomplish?

Comment: No, I know how can I open a link with "default" browser. I want to know how can I open this link with a different browser.